# How to use a class with a context argument in a static context without causing a memory leak?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-context

In my project I have this situation. This is a part of my `MainActivity`, I have initialized the object `helperClass` with the `applicationContext` and made it static because I have to use it in the `OnClickListener` of a button:

```
public class MainActivity {
    public static HelperClass helperClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        helperClass = new HelperClass(getApplicationContext());

        {...}

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                helperClass.doSomething();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is a part of the helper class, I need the context because I have to store some data in the app memory:

```
public class HelperClass{
    private Context context;

    public HelperClass(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "name");
        {...}
    }
}
```

Now, this code **works**, but when I declare `helperClass` static there is a warning saying this is a memory leak; I tried to remove the context from the `HelperClass` but I could not retrieve the context from the class; I also tried to remove the static declaration but I need it because the `OnClickListener` is a static context.

I read [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) that I can use `ApplicationContext`, it is ok but it's an old article.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to make a field static in order to use it in the Listener. Moreover, you shouldn't, as you correctly said that it may lead to a memory leak :-) Just remove the *static* keyword, run the code and it will work ^^

Comment: If I remove the static keyword it says that non-static field helperClass cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: @Darcar90 from the code you've posted, this is the correct solution and should work. Are you making any other static references that you've omitted to show us?

Comment: @Darcar90 please post the code that causes that error

Comment: @brandall you are right, I was actually calling the listener in a static method called in 'onCreate', my bad. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if removing static declaration is preventing you from memory leaks you can remove the static declaration and access helper class from onClick() method like this.

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.this.helperClass.doSomething();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried also this, it says that MainActivity.this is non-static and cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: have you remove static keyword from helper class?

Comment: Yes, I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Context of the HelperClass and send the context through the method *doSomething( Context )* to avoid your problem.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        helperClass.doSomething(v.getContext());
    }
});
```

So sending the Context this way you didn't need to have it as a global variable.

```
public class HelperClass{

    public HelperClass() {
    }

    public void doSomething(Context context) {
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "name");
        {...}
    }
}
```